# Limit macro_rules! literal to certain integers

Tags: rust, macro-rules

## Problem

How can I create a Rust macro that only accepts certain number literals in a scalable manor?

Ideally, such a solution meets the following requirements:

- Scales to hundreds of allowed numbers
- Raises compile time errors *where the macro is called* when the number literal is invalid

## Non-solutions

### Multiple branches

You can create a macro where each arm accepts a specific number as shown below. However I also want to perform computation on the allowed numbers, leading to lots of code duplication since I'm dealing with hundreds of allowed numbers.

```rust
macro_rules! my_macro {
    (1) => {
        1
    };
    (2) => {
        2
    };
    (3) => {
        3
    };
}
```

### Using `compile_error!`

The `compile_error!` macro reports the error inside `my_macro`, not on the arguments to `my_macro!`. This can be very unintuitive.

```rust
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($num: literal) => {
        // if number is invalid
        compile_error!("number is invalid")
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ // error is reported here

        // else
        $num
    };
}

// Let's say 34 is an invalid number
my_macro!(34)
```

## Context

I'm trying to emulate a behavior with TypeScript's type system where you can create a type that limits the specific numbers a function accepts.

```
type AllowedNumbers = 1 | 2 | 3

const myFunc = (num: AllowedNumbers) => {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It depends on those numbers you want to accept.

Comment: How about multiple branches + internal rules to avoid code duplication: `macro_rules! my_macro { (@internal $x:lit) => { todo!() }, (1) => { my_macro!(@internal 1) }, … }`

Comment: Be aware of the difference between compile time checks and runtime checks. Are TypeScript's type system compile time checks? Because Rust can only do compile time checks.

Comment: With literals TypeScript will check this at compile time. For expressions, you'd either need to do lot's of type hackery or rely on runtime checks. TypeScript will check this scenario at compile time, though, because I'm only concerned with literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can panic in a const to create a compile-time error dependent on a literal.

```rs
macro_rules! one_to_ten {
    ($n:literal) => {
        const _: () = if $n < 1 || $n > 10 {
            panic!("was not between 1 and 10")
        };
    };
}
```

This produces the following error.

```rs
error[E0080]: evaluation of constant value failed
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     one_to_ten!(20);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the evaluated program panicked at 'was not between 1 and 10', src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::panic::panic_2021` which comes from the expansion of the macro `one_to_ten` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Your idea to use `compile_error` doesn't work anyway since there's no way to conditionally compile it based on the value of a literal besides using multiple branches.

I think this is as good as you'll get with declarative macros. You could create better error messages if you write a procedural macro.

Comment: Why not `assert!($n >= 1 && $n <= 10, "{} is not between 1 and 10", $n)`?

Comment: @cafce25 Assert works fine but doesn't really change the error. You can't use format parameters in const, but since it's a literal, you can use `concat!`.

Comment: It doesn't change much but you're essentialy rebuilding assert.